# Where to get electrodes for Microbial fuel cell

Tags: redox

I am currently working on a soil-based MFC. So far I have built myself some carbon electrodes by putting glue on a stainless steel mesh as a current collector and sprinkling activated carbon power over it. I have yet to try this but after some research people with far more advanced materials have only gained the amount of energy I am looking for.

Could anyone point me to a source of carbon electrodes, preferably flat ones, since I only found brush electrodes and those won't help my cause. Pricetag does not matter too much for now, I an curious to see what options I have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's likely to attract spam. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proton Exchange Membrane (PEM) is designed for polymer electrolyte membrane fuel cells (PEMFC). Read this article first to decide: PEM fuel cell electrodes (review): *Journal of Power Sources*, **2004**, *130(1-2)*, 61–76 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpowsour.2003.12.055). The review is available online, courtesy of Univ. of Connecticut: http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jmfent/electrode%20review.pdf

PEM is available to buy online (albeit expensive): http://www.fuelcellstore.com/fuel-cell-components/membranes
http://www.fuelcellstore.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=Proton%20Exchange%20Membrane

Also available following carbon cloth electrodes, if you want cheap replace ment. One example is:

0.03 mg/cm² 20% Platinum on Vulcan - Carbon Cloth Electrode (Product Code: 1610000): A low-cost electrode utilizing a woven carbon cloth substrate and a 20% Platinum on Vulcan Carbon support catalyst.  This low loading is designed for cost sensitive applications and is suitable for electrochemical systems needing low amounts of Platinum to support the reaction.  This electrode is perfect for Hydrogen/Air Fuel Cell applications where the extra cost of the higher loading GDE may not be justified.
You can order on line,
http://www.fuelcellstore.com/003-ptc-cloth-electrode

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score -1):

The growing interest in organic photovoltaics and the potential for a future mass production urges to find alternatives to the presently employed materials that are well performing but not convenient from the point of view of large area fabrication. Electrodes based on non abundant elements, or that constitute an issue for devices (i) long term stability, (ii) mechanical robustness and (iii) continuous fabrication process, shall be possibly soon replaced by earth abundant, easy processable and sustainable materials. Many groups have recently started to devote their research work on materials not containing metals or metal oxides, and the time has come to summarise the progress that has been reached so far.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927024811007185>

Answer (score -1):

https://www.intechopen.com/books/carbon-nanotubes-current-progress-of-their-polymer-composites/carbon-nanotubes-supported-conducting-polymer-electrode-for-supercapacitor
Carbon Nanotubes Supported Conducting Polymer Electrode

highly stable chemically